# Pandas: create new columns by linearly interpolating between existing columns

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a `dataframe` of weekly reported profit on every Friday containing 5 years data.

DataFrame looks like:

**UPDATED DATA:**

```
  Date      Profit
7/28/2017   2,923 
7/21/2017   2,879 
7/14/2017   2,832 
7/7/2017    2,773 
6/30/2017   2,701 
6/23/2017   2,635 
6/16/2017   2,563 
6/9/2017    2,481 
6/2/2017    2,394 
:
7/29/2016   2,824 
7/22/2016   2,770 
7/15/2016   2,718 
7/8/2016    2,657 
7/1/2016    2,580 
6/24/2016   2,503 
6/17/2016   2,425 
6/10/2016   2,337 
6/3/2016    2,250 
:
7/31/2015   2,848 
7/24/2015   2,796 
7/17/2015   2,748 
7/10/2015   2,694 
7/3/2015    2,623 
6/26/2015   2,548 
6/19/2015   2,474 
6/12/2015   2,387 
6/5/2015    2,301 
:
```

I would like to `interpolate` profit on the same date of the previous years irrespective of the weekday for that date and fill the below 3rd and 4th columns.

```
    week_ending    profit   Profit one_yr_ago           Profilt 2_yrs_ago
0    2017-07-28    3,010    (Profit on 2016-07-28)      (profit on 2015-07-28)
1    2017-07-21    2,990    (Profit on 2016-07-21)      (profit on 2015-07-21)     
2    2017-07-14    2,973           --                        --
3    2017-07-07    2,945           --                        --
4    2017-06-30    2,888
5    2017-06-23    2,816
6    2017-06-16    2,770
7    2017-06-09    2,709
8    2017-06-02    2,631
9    2017-05-26    2,525
```

I have tried using `np.interp` and `x[0] - pd.DateOffset(years=1)` for previous year but not sure how to to get this done. Should I use rolling_apply to do it efficiently ?

**EDIT**
@JohanL and @Cheryl : Data is captured every Friday. Eg: we know 2017-07-28 is a Friday but 2016-07-28 is not a Friday. In the new columns, I would like to interpolate the profit for the same date last year and two years ago. I have updated the actual dataFrame to represent 3 years data for June and July months.

Comment: What is it that you want to interpolate to find? The profit of the same day a year (or multiple years) ago, using the available dates from that year? It is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# function to return last n year's date
def previous_n_year(x, n):
    return x - pd.DateOffset(years=n)

# some sample data
dt_str = ['2017-07-28', '2017-07-21', '2017-07-14', '2017-07-07', '2016-07-28', '2016-07-21', '2016-07-14', '2015-07-28']
dates = [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in dt_str]
profit = [3010, 2990, 2973, 2945, 2888, 2816, 2770, 2709]
df = pd.DataFrame({'profit':profit, 'week_ending': dates})
df = df.set_index(['week_ending'])
df['profit_last_year'] = np.nan  # empty column to store profit of one year ago
df['profit_2_years_ago'] = np.nan  # empty column to store profit of two years ago

# check if there is a profit for previous n years and then fill that in the new column
for idx in df.index:
    if previous_n_year(idx, 1) in df.index:
        df.loc[idx, 'profit_last_year'] = df.loc[previous_n_year(idx,1), 'profit']
    if previous_n_year(idx, 2) in df.index:
        df.loc[idx, 'profit_2_years_ago'] = df.loc[previous_n_year(idx,2), 'profit']
```

The result:

```
             profit  profit_last_year  profit_2_years_ago
week_ending                                              
2017-07-28     3010            2888.0              2709.0
2017-07-21     2990            2816.0                 NaN
2017-07-14     2973            2770.0                 NaN
2017-07-07     2945               NaN                 NaN
2016-07-28     2888            2709.0                 NaN
2016-07-21     2816               NaN                 NaN
2016-07-14     2770               NaN                 NaN
2015-07-28     2709               NaN                 NaN
```

---

EDIT

I understand now that the date for the previous year is different so you have to interpolate. I edited the following: 
The dataframe with date as index:

```
             profit
2017-07-28     3010
2017-07-21     2990
2017-07-14     2973
2017-07-07     2945
2016-07-28     2888
2016-07-21     2816
2016-07-14     2770
2015-07-28     2709
```

We get the dates from one year ago and the total:

```
dates_min1 = [previous_n_year(pd.Timestamp(x),1) for x in dt_str]
dates_total = dates + dates_min1
```

I reindex the dataframe and interpolate for the added dates:

```
df1 = df.reindex(dates_total).sort_index(ascending = False).interpolate(method = 'cubic')
```

I create two separate dataframes again and reset the index. Then I concatenate them again.

```
df_profit = df1.loc[dates].reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'date'})
df_profit_min1 = df1.loc[dates_min1].rename(columns = {'profit':'profit_min1'}).reset_index(drop = True)
result = pd.concat([df_profit, df_profit_min1], axis = 1)
```

The result:

```
         date  profit  profit_min1
0  2017-07-28  2923.0  2816.334310
1  2017-07-21  2879.0  2762.637100
2  2017-07-14  2832.0  2709.779097
3  2017-07-07  2773.0  2648.302836
4  2016-07-29  2824.0  2833.154115
5  2016-07-22  2770.0  2782.006404
6  2016-07-15  2718.0  2733.852340
7  2016-07-08  2657.0          NaN
8  2015-07-31  2848.0          NaN
9  2015-07-24  2796.0          NaN
10 2015-07-17  2748.0          NaN
11 2015-07-10  2694.0          NaN
```

Comment: This works well if I have data for the same dates every year. But data is present for every Friday.